# wrong matching for string containing '[' at start

Tags: java, regex

My code is below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(validateusername("$asd123"));

    }

    static boolean validateusername(String s)
    {
        if(s.matches("[a-zA-z]+[0-9]*"))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

This is giving **true** for **' [abc1 '**

**' [ '** character should not be treated as **a-zA-z** , why its giving **true**.

**But for any other special character it is giving false , ' _ '(underscore) and  ' [ ' it is giving true;**

What I have tried -

-- i tried putting **' ^ '** in start of string but its not working still.

-- i tried to escape **' [ '** character by putting **' / '** , not working.

Comment: i have tried this on jdk 6 and 7 , both are giving same ,dont know what causing problem..did u execute this on your machine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is `[a-zA-z]`, you mentioned the range `A` to `z` inside the character class. `[` symbol falls within the range capital `A` to small `z`, so it returns true.

See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the symbols which falls within the range `A` to `z` .

Comment: I was few seconds late. mention the changes needed as well.

Comment: one more thing i want to ask , to make it work to start with aplhabet , is this valid regex  , or i have ti put ' ^ ' in start of regex ?

Comment: try `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*`

Comment: yeah that is what i changed now , its working  , i am asking if i need to put ^ in start of string , to make it accept only alphabet in start

Comment: you said "STring.mactches have  `^`  by default"

Comment: @anshulkatta not needed, `matches` looks for whole string match.